# From semantic perspective, what's the moment an undefined behavior of `&mut` noalias occurred in Rust?

Tags: rust, llvm, undefined-behavior, unsafe

As Rust reference documention said

> Breaking the pointer aliasing rules. &mut T and &T follow LLVM’s scoped noalias model, except if the &T contains an UnsafeCell.

It's really ambiguous.
I want to know that what's the exactly moment an undefined behavior of `&mut` noalias occurred in Rust.

Is it any of below, or something else?

> 1. When defining two `&mut` that point to the same address?
> 2. When two `&mut` that point to the same address exposed to rust?
> 3. When perfrom any operation on a `&mut` that point to the same address of any other `&mut`?

For example, [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=325606e67c7a4b6078214bef852f2248) is observously UB:

```rust
unsafe {
    let mut x = 123usize;
    let a = (&mut x as *mut usize).as_mut().unwrap(); // created, but not accessed
    let b = (&mut x as *mut usize).as_mut().unwrap(); // created, accessed
    *b = 666;
    drop(a);
}
```

But what if I modify the code like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e6b55ac2c7f00a8783d7e428be8d5be):

```rust
struct S<'a> {
    ref_x: &'a mut usize
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 123;
    let s = S { ref_x: &mut x }; // like the `T` in `ManuallyDrop<T>`
    let taken = unsafe { std::ptr::read(&s as *const S) }; // like `ManuallyDrop<T>::take`
    // at thist ime, we have two `&mut x`
    *(taken.ref_x) = 666;
    drop(s);
    // UB or not?
}
```

Is the second version also UB?
The second version is totally the same implemention to [std::mem::ManuallyDrop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/struct.ManuallyDrop.html#method.take). If the second version is UB, is it a security bug of `std::mem::ManuallyDrop<T>`?

Comment: "It is your responsibility to ensure that this ManuallyDrop is not used again" - does this quote from the documentation you link to answer your question?

Comment: @Cerberus No. In the first example, we didn't dereference `a` but it's UB. In the second example, which is the same implemention to `ManuallyDrop<T>`, we also made two aliasing `&mut` reference but only deferenced one, just like `ensure that this ManuallyDrop is not used again`, shouldn't it be also UB?

Comment: I am sorry but I just plain don't understand the questions of (2) and (3), (1) was clear, but I fail to see how "exposed to Rust" in (2) makes a difference from (1), and in (3) it's not clear to me why performing an operation would cause an issue...

Comment: If you're asking if the `ManuallyDrop` implementation is unsound, then you should follow its contract. If you remove `drop(s)` from your second snippet (which explicitly contradicts this contract), it will probably be no problem - and if it's UB too, then, well, this is something with the fact that `ManuallyDrop` is the lang item, i.e. special-cased by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

#### What the aliasing restriction is not

It is actually common to have *multiple* existing `&mut T` aliasing the same item.

The simplest example is:

```
fn main() {
   let mut i = 32;
   let j = &mut i;
   let k = &mut *j;

   *k = 3;

   println!("{}", i);
}
```

Note, though, that due to *borrowing rules* you cannot *access* the other aliases simultaneously.

If you look at the implementation of `ManuallyDrop::take`:

> ```
> pub unsafe fn take(slot: &mut ManuallyDrop<T>) -> T {
>     ptr::read(&slot.value)
> }
> ```

You will note that there are no *simultaneously* accessible `&mut T`: calling the function re-borrows `ManuallyDrop` making `slot` the only accessible mutable reference.

#### Why is aliasing in Rust so ill-defined

> It's really ambiguous. I want to know that what's the exactly moment an undefined behavior of `&mut` noalias occurred in Rust.

Tough luck, because as specified in the [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/references.html):

> Unfortunately, Rust hasn't actually defined its aliasing model.

The reason is that the language team wants to make sure that the definition they reach is both *safe* (demonstrably so), *practical*, and yet does not *close the door* to possible refinements. It's a tall order.

The [Rust Unsafe Code Guidelines Working Group](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines) is still working on establishing the exact boundaries, and in particular Ralf Jung is working on an operational model for aliasing called [Stacked Borrows](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/rustbelt/stacked-borrows/paper.pdf).

*Note: the Stacked Borrows model is implemented in MIRI, and therefore you can validate your code against the Stacked Borrows model simply by executing your code in MIRI. Of course Stacked Borrows is still experimental, so this doesn't guarantee anything.*

#### What caution recommends

I personally subscribe to caution. Seeing as the exact model is unspecified, the rules are *ever changing* and therefore I recommend taking the *stricter* interpretation possible.

Thus, I interpret the no-aliasing rule of `&mut T` as:

> At any point in the code, there shall not be two accessible references in scope which alias the same memory if one of them is `&mut T`.

That is, I consider that *forming* a `&mut T` to an instance `T` for which another `&T` or `&mut T` is in scope *without* invalidating the aliases (via borrowing) is ill-formed.

It may very well be overly cautious, but at least if the aliasing model ends up being more conservative than planned, my code will still be valid.